# How to get id value dynamically in an object in typescript

Tags: json, angularjs, typescript

I have a question about how to get id value dynamically in an object in typescript. I can give you an example:

input object looks like this:

```js
station = {
  id: "123123",
  address: {
    id: "asdfasd",
    type: "street"
    value: "asdfas"
  },
  station: {
    id: "asdsdfsdfasd",
    type: "trainstation"
    value: "asdfsdfsas"
  },
  information: {
    id: "asdsdfsdfasd",
    school: {
      id: "asdsdsdsfsdfasd",
      type: "middleschool"
      value: "asdfssdsddfsas"
    }
  }
}
```

how can I get parent id dynamiclly, if I give a parameter such as "shool", then I can get id of information?

any solutions

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what are you looking for:**

```js
const station = {"id":"123123","address":{"id":"asdfasd","type":"street","value":"asdfas"},"station":{"id":"asdsdfsdfasd","type":"trainstation","value":"asdfsdfsas"},"information":{"id":"asdsdfsdfasd","school":{"id":"asdsdsdsfsdfasd","type":"middleschool","value":"asdfssdsddfsas"}}};


function getId(obj, key){
let id;
Object.keys(obj, key).forEach(x=>{
if(x == key){
 id = obj[x].id; return id;
}
else{
if(typeof(obj[x]) == 'object'){ id = getId(obj[x], key)};
}
});
return id;
};

console.log(getId(station, 'school'));
```